# Kotlin's reduce() function with different types

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

I was looking through array extension functions and found `reduce()` one

```
inline fun <S, T: S> Array<out T>.reduce(operation: (acc: S, T) -> S): S {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Empty array can't be reduced.")
    var accumulator: S = this[0]
    for (index in 1..lastIndex) {
        accumulator = operation(accumulator, this[index])
    }
    return accumulator
}
```

here the `accumulator` variable of type `S` assigned with first element from the array with type `T`.

Can't wrap my head around the real use case of `reduce()` function with two data types. Here synthetic example which actually doesn't make any sense.

```
open class A(var width: Int = 0)
class B(width: Int) : A(width)

val array = arrayOf(A(7), A(4), A(1), A(4), A(3))
val res = array.reduce { acc, s -> B(acc.width + s.width) }
```

Seems most real life use cases with this function use this signature:

```
inline fun <T> Array<out T>.reduce(operation: (acc: T, T) -> T): T
```

Can you help with providing some examples, where `reduce()` function can be useful with different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
interface Expr {
    val value: Int
}

class Single(override val value: Int): Expr

class Sum(val a: Expr, val b: Expr): Expr {
    override val value: Int
        get() = a.value + b.value
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val arr = arrayOf(Single(1), Single(2), Single(3));
    val result = arr.reduce<Expr, Single> { a, b -> Sum(a, b) }
    println(result.value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you need to use [fold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html), where the accumulator type might be different from the array elements:

```
inline fun <T, R> Array<out T>.fold(
    initial: R,
    operation: (acc: R, T) -> R
): R
```