# Is there a sumBy equivalent for multiplication?

Tags: kotlin

I have an array of classes with values. E.g.

```
class MyData(val value: Double)

class MyClass(val values: List<MyData>)
```

it's pretty easy to get the sum of all values in the array:

```
values.sumByDouble { it.value }
```

Is there an equivalent to multiply these values inside those classes?

Comment: You can use [reduce](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html)

Comment: Does not seem like a very elegant solution to me, as seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50887454/6191842)

Comment: @DanielGretzke I see what you mean now. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dedicated function for that, but you can use [reduce](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html) for that. But there is a problem. Since the element (in this case of type `T` with `S` as upper bound) has to be a subtype of the accumulator (in this case of type `S`),

```
inline fun <S, T : S> Iterable<T>.reduce(
    operation: (acc: S, T) -> S
): S
```

which is not the case in your example, it would be a good idea to first map the `MyData` elements to the `Double` value:

```
val l = listOf(MyData(1.0), MyData(2.0), MyData(3.0))
    .map { it.value }
    .reduce { acc, ele -> acc * ele }

println(l) // 6.0
```

Alternatively, you could change your data model (like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50887454/1788806)) but that might not be a good idea just for the sake of multiplying all values, but it depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an extension function:

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.multiplyByDouble(selector: (T) -> Double): Double {
    this.firstOrNull() ?: return 0.0
    var result = 1.0
    for (element in this) {
        result *= selector(element)
    }
    return result
}
```

and use it:

```
listOf(2.0, 3.0).multiplyByDouble { it }  // 6.0
listOf<Double>().multiplyByDouble { it }  // 0.0
```